# How to Show and Hide div using AngularJS? without using any css or jquery

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide a div and show it on button click using angularJS?
I used ng-show and ng-hide but it's not working

Comment: Post some code of what you tried so far.

Comment: Post your code please. The complete HTML for your page and if there's a controller, the javascript file as well.

Comment: Where's your code examples for this question?

Comment: i got an answer and got that fixed Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div ng-show="anyVariable"></div>

<button ng-click="anyVariable = !anyVariable">Click</button>
```

Comment: not working is there anything i need to do with Javascript?